# Grep command in ruby during iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can do it in shell script , but wanted to try in ruby since learning, please help on this.

While trying to grep the the variable (`line`)from the file (`list`) during iteration , no output is showing

However while doing separately like below , can see the output

```
Getting Output: ("Phone" is one of the lines present in the file)

    value = `grep -i "phone" list`
        puts value

 No Output:
     File.open("list") do |f|
            f.each_line do |line|
            puts line
            value = `grep -i "line" list`
    #       puts list
            puts value
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby way of writing that would be something like this:

```
File.open('list').each_line.grep(/phone/i)
```

Documentation:

- [IO#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-each_line)
- [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)